# Replacement for unique(rbind()) when using data.tables

Tags: r, data.table

So, I have many data.tables I wish to combine into a single data.table with no duplicate rows. 
The 'naive' way to do this is to wrap an rbind call with unique: `unique(do.call(rbind, list.of.tables))`

This certainly works, but its pretty slow. In my real-world case the tables have two columns; a hash string and size. At this point in the code, they are un-keyed. I have played around with keying by hash first, but the gain in combining is offset by the time to key.

Here's how I benchmarked those options:

```
require(data.table)

makeHash <- function(numberOfHashes) {

  hashspace <- c(0:9, sapply(97:122, function(x) rawToChar(as.raw(x))))
  replicate(numberOfHashes, paste(sample(hashspace, 16), collapse=""))

}

mergeNoKey <- function(tableLength, modCount=tableLength/2) {

  A <- B <- data.table(hash=makeHash(tableLength), size=sample(1:(1024^2), tableLength))

  A[1:modCount] <- data.table(hash=makeHash(modCount), size=sample(1:(1024^2), modCount))

  C <- unique(rbind(A,B))
}

mergeWithKey <- function(tableLength, modCount=tableLength/2) {

  A <- B <- data.table(hash=makeHash(tableLength), size=sample(1:(1024^2), tableLength))

  A[1:modCount] <- data.table(hash=makeHash(modCount), size=sample(1:(1024^2), modCount))

  setkey(A, hash)
  setkey(B, hash)

  C <- unique(rbind(A,B))
}

require(microbenchmark)
m <- microbenchmark(mergeNoKey(1000), mergeWithKey(1000), times=10)
plot(m)
```

I've played around with tableLength and times and seen no big difference in performance. I feel like there HAS to be a more data.table-ish way to do this.

In practice I need to do this with many data.tables, not two, so scalability is very important; I just wanted to keep the above code simple.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you want to use `rbindlist` and `unique.data.table`...

```
C <- unique( rbindlist( list( A , B ) ) )
```

Comment: +1 Btw, `unique` gains `by` in v1.8.10 (on CRAN) for more flexibility (thanks to Steve), and `list()` no longer copies named inputs (as in this example) in GNU R v3.1.0 (which v1.8.10 knows about and likes).

Comment: Wow, surprised I missed that. I'm getting a more modest gain than I was hoping for; is there no better way?

Comment: @ClaytonJY take the `rbinding` out of the function and test *just* the difference in `rbind` vs. `rbindlist`. I think you'll find most of the time is spent elsewhere in your functions.

Comment: @MatthewDowle -- Very interesting. Does that mean that `ab <- list(a,b)` doesn't actually immediately copy `a` and `b`? Or are there some other rules for when `a` and `b` are copied, and when they aren't?

Comment: @SimonO101 You're definitely correct about the time being spent elsewhere. The `rbind` is part of my custom `.combine` function in a parallel `foreach` job; for time reasons im only testing on a small subset of my actual dataset, but since i have `.multicombine=TRUE` I expect I will see better improvments the more data I feed in. Marked as best, thanks!

Comment: @JoshO'Brien That's right, `ab <- list(a,b)` won't copy `a` or `b`, just increment the reference counter (NAMED) instead. Since `list` is primitive as well, and we use `list()` quite a lot in data.table (both internally and in queries) it might make a significant difference (haven't tested yet).